# countdown timer using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to create a countdown timer that takes countdown, from 60 seconds down to 0. I'm not sure A. How to limit the repeats to 60 and 0. How to decrement the countdown in

Comment: should not be an issue with setTimeout , but you need to try something before asking.

Comment: There are lots of questions concerning timers, search for them. Btw, <canvas> has nothing to do with all of them - those are two different problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit your question has nothing to do with canvas, but here is the code for the countdown :)

```
(function(){     
    var sec = 60;  
    var id = window.setInterval(function() {
        sec--;
        if (sec < - 1) {
            clearInterval(id);
            alert("Time complete");
            return;
        }        
    }, 1000/60)
})();
```

Comment: thanx...a lot.. i too apllied the same logic but i wanted it in the canvas means a clock shape with countdown inside the clock

Comment: Here is one of the many possibilities: http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/clock/#clock. You should check the source code.

Comment: I did it like this but my clock hands are getting reprinted . here is the code i wrote what changes can i make

Comment: i used it in clock() but by doing that only hands are appearing the background is not appeared

Comment: hey i got it i just made changes in dimensions 
ctx.fillStyle="BurlyWood ";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,125,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();


realy thanx a lot to u